# Fetching all uploaded, tagged in and share videos in Facebook by FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

In my app, I want to fetch all videos of logged in user i.e. videos that are uploaded by user, videos share by user, user tagged in etc. Currently I'm using "stream" query as:

```
SELECT created_time, post_id, actor_id, type, updated_time,
   attachment FROM stream WHERE created_time>1075593600
   AND type IN (56, 80, 128, 237, 272) AND source_id=me() limit 10000
```

As you can see I use "type IN" to fetch required videos but this query is not fetching all videos of mine. I have two videos in 2011 one of which is uploaded and other one is shared. But I'm not getting these two.

Also in developer.facebook it was written that:

> Each query of the stream table is limited to the previous 30 days or 50 posts, whichever is greater, however you can use time-specific fields such as created_time along with FQL operators (such as < or >) to retrieve a much greater range of posts.

So I tried "created time>0" i.e.(1970) and other like timestamp of 2001 but still I'm not getting all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in single facebook query. I also implemented it using single query but i faced issues with it.